# SchemaParseException while doing a join in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have written a simple pig script which reads data from 2 files as avro records. Then I do a join on them based on ids on both files. Example `sample.pig`:

```
sample1 = LOAD '/dumpedFromAnotherPigScript' using AvroStorage();
sample2 = LOAD '/fromExistingFile' using AvroStorage();
describe sample1;
sample1: {rootObjectId: chararray, orderId: long}
describe sample2;
sample2: {objectId: chararray, name: chararray}
joined = join sample2 by objectId, sample1 by rootObjectId;
store joined into '/joinedpath';
```

When I do a join like this, I get a SchemaParseException while doing `PigSchema2Avro.convertRecord()`. The exception message is: `Illegal character in: sample2::objectId`

This is happening only when I try to do a join. It works fine when I just do a dump. Also sample1 is actually loaded from a file whose contents are populated from yet another pig script `first-sample.pig` using `AvroStorage`. sample2 is loaded from an existing file containing avro records. The strange part is, if I do not store records from `first-sample.pig` into `/dumpedFromAnotherPigScript` location and directly merge `sample.pig` script with this, it all works fine. I'm unable to understand the difference here. Any clues?